# "Meh" questions should be pruned after aging

Tags: feature-request, voting, area-51, example-questions

"Meh" questions serve little purpose on Area51 - they are obvious, and lend no assistance in determining what the site is about.

Once a proposal reaches 20 followers or so (ie, there are many people actively interested in making sure the proposal moves forward on an ongoing basis), then questions which don't receive at least X votes by Y time after being submitted should be auto-deleted as 'meh.'

- This keeps the question list small
- Focuses the group on those questions people actually care about
- Forces people to accept that there *is* a meh vote and it *does* matter without explicitly having a meh vote
- Automates what should be happening within groups that have good 'shepherds'

I'm thinking that proposals with at least 20 followers should drop questions that receive fewer than 2 total votes within 7 days of being posted, but that's just a WAG based on my experience with the site.

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking that proposals with at least 20 followers should drop questions that receive fewer than 2 total votes within 7 days of being posted.

Comment: Wow, it's like you're reading my mind!

Comment: I don't agree with the OP, but this might work